# I need add only property a 4 objects

Tags: c#

I making a tetris, need add property gravity and move all object, 
my problem is that I do it object by object and i would like it can add property for all object

Class Piece:

```
interface Figura
{
    void MoverI(); //Izquierda
    void MoverD(); //Derecha
    void RotarI(); //Rotacion
    void RotarD();
    void Gravedad();
}

class Square : Figura
{
    public SolidColorBrush C = new SolidColorBrush();
    public Rectangle _P = new Rectangle();
    public int X,
               Y,
               YDIR = 5,
               XDIR = 10;
    const int TAM = 10;
    protected Canvas c;

    public Square(Canvas c, int X, int Y)
    {      
        _P.Width = TAM;
        _P.Height = TAM;
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        C.Color = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);
        _P.Fill = C;
        Canvas.SetLeft(_P, X);
        Canvas.SetTop(_P, Y);
        c.Children.Add(_P);
    }

    void Figura.Gravedad()
    {
        Y += YDIR;
        Canvas.SetTop(_P, Y);
    }
```

Class MainWindows

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
        A = new Square(Canvas, 50, 50);
        A1 = new Square(Canvas, 50, 60);
        A2 = new Square(Canvas, 60, 50);
        A3 = new Square(Canvas, 60, 60);

        DP = new DispatcherTimer();
        DP.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 80);
        DP.Tick += new EventHandler(DP_TICK);
        DP.IsEnabled = true;
        MatrizTetris = new int[100, 100];
    }

    public void DP_TICK(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        A.Gravedad();
        A1.Gravedad();
        A2.Gravedad();
        A3.Gravedad();
    }
```

For example:

```
        A.Gravedad();
        A1.Gravedad();
        A2.Gravedad();
        A3.Gravedad();
```

other method of making to add all property or regroup A, A1, A2, A3 and add Gravedad?

Comment: I'm really confused with your question, could you clarify?

Comment: i want you to join A, A1 A2, A3 and add the gravity property equally

Comment: I don't understand but for a tetris game, the gravity for each block should be 1. It's the speed of the game that changes.

Comment: i know, but my problem es A.Gravedad(), repeat A1.Gravedad() i search only method more efficient

Comment: Hint: Any time you have repeating code, it is time to consider arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You could maintain a list of all objects within the class:

```
ICollection<Figura> _objects;
```

Initialize this in the `MainWindow` constructor:

```
_objects = new List<Figura> { A, A1, A2, A3 };
```

And then in `DP_TICK` you can iterate over all of the objects and call your method:

```
foreach (var x in _objects)
    x.Gravedad();
```